# Beginner: How to present UITableView programmatically from another view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have already created UITableViewController embedded in Navigator Controller using Storyboard and Interface Builder.

I would like to display this UITableViewController programmatically from a different UIViewController that I already have.

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

In particular, read about container view controllers (like `UINavigationControllers` and how to push new view controllers onto its stack) and presenting view controllers temporarily (which describes how to present a modal view controller).